# Are today's Rajputs descendants of Kshatriyas of previous yugas?

Tags: history, kshatriya, chandravansh, suryavansh

Are today's Rajputs descendants of Kshatriyas of Dwapara Yuga and Treta Yuga?

In Short are Rajputs descendants of Shri Rama, Shri Krishna and Pandavas?

Comment: Varna Ashrama is not same as Caste System. Please correct your question title. It is not looking relevant with your question body.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto According to who? Neo-Hindus? Yes

Answer (score 2):

Rajput are a sub-caste or order of Kshatriyas but not all kshtariyas call themselves rajput. 
Kshatriyas were of three origins : suryavanshi, chandravanshi and agnivanshi (some include fourth as nagvanshi). 
These are found throughout India with different names of their sub-castes. 
Rajput is a predominant sub-caste of kshtariyas in North-Central India.

Solar kshtariyas : it is related to house of ikshwaku and bhagwan Ram bhadra. http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03106.htm

Lunar kshtariyas : these are related to house of kshtariyas of Mahabharata.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_dynasty

Agnikula kshtariyas : 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnivansha